# Careers 2.0 Bitbucket.org error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, 500-server-error

Every time I try to add project from Bitbucket.org in my `http://careers.stackoverflow.com` I get an error - "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" with two puppet guys image.

I'm getting this when clicking on right menu in profile view and in "add or update:" in `Open Source` section.
I host my projects mostly on bitbucket.org.

How can I add my Bitbucket projects? Or there is some other way to do this (that don't end up with error)?

Comment: We are seeing this too, and at the moment we think it’s a Bitbucket issue. Working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was an intermittent Bitbucket error.  It should be working now.